# Google Visualization - Specify Type from Query

Tags: google-visualization

I am creating a dashboard that queries a published google spreadsheet as the dataTable.  The charts (column, table, and candlestick) show up just fine.  However, I have added a listener event for 'sort' on the table and would like this to sort the corresponding data in the column and candlestick charts.  However, when I sort the table by clicking on the header, the charts show the following error in red:

"All data columns of the same series must be of the same data type".

My spreadsheet contains a string for the first column and numbers for the other columns.  However, I assume that I am getting this error message because the query is not returning the data as 'string' in the first column and 'number' in the other columns.  Can I specify this?  If so, how?  Thanks.

EDIT: Here is my code...the addListener event at the bottom is causing the issue:

```
var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AukymWvA6LlzdHpwblVtSmU3ZXJOMGhUVFZiV3NnSkE&single=true&gid=0&output=html');

query.setQuery('SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T');

query.send(function (response) {        
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }
    var data = response.getDataTable();

    // CategoryFilter for Grade
    var gradeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
        containerId: 'gradeFilter_div',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 3
        }
    });

    // CategoryFilter for School
    var schoolFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
        containerId: 'schoolFilter_div',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 16
        }
    });

    // CategoryFilter for Teacher
    var teacherFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
        containerId: 'teacherFilter_div',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 17
        }
    });

    // CategoryFilter for Entity
    var entityFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
        containerId: 'entityFilter_div',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 18
        }
    });

    var numberSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
        containerId: 'rNumberRangeFilter_div',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 19
        }
    });

    // create a Table visualization
    var rBubbleChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'BubbleChart',
        containerId: 'rBubble_div',
        options: {
            title: 'Comparison of Percentiles',
            height: 500,
            width: 500,
            chartArea:{left:"10%",top:"10%",width:"80%",height:"80%"},
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            bubble: {opacity: 0.6, stroke: 'transparent', textStyle: {fontSize: 8, color: 'transparent'}},
            hAxis: {minValue: 0, maxValue: 100, gridlines: {count: 11, color: '#EEEEEE'}, title: '2013 Percentile', titleTextStyle: {fontSize:10}, textStyle: {fontSize:10}},
            vAxis: {minValue: 0, maxValue: 100, gridlines: {count: 11, color: '#EEEEEE'}, title: '2014 Percentile', titleTextStyle: {fontSize:10}, textStyle: {fontSize:10}},
            colors: ['#a4c2f4','#89B0F0','#6d9eeb','#558BE2','#3c78d8','#2767D2','#1155cc'],
            legend: {position: 'in', alignment: 'center', textStyle: {fontSize:10}},
            animation: {duration:1500, easing:'out'},
            sizeAxis: {minSize: 2, minValue: 5, maxSize: 30, maxValue: 500}
        },
        view: {columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
    });

    //Draw chart with y=x line
    var hackChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'LineChart',
        containerId: 'hack_chart_div',
        dataTable: [['x', 'y'],[0, 0], [100, 100]],
        options: {
            height: 500,
            width: 500,
            chartArea:{left:"10%",top:"10%",width:"80%",height:"80%"},
            hAxis: {minValue: 0, maxValue: 100, textPosition: 'none', gridlines: {count: 0}, baselineColor: 'none'},
            vAxis: {minValue: 0, maxValue: 100, textPosition: 'none', gridlines: {count: 0}, baselineColor: 'none'},
            colors: ['black'],
            pointSize: 0,
            lineWidth: 1,
            enableInteractivity: false,
            legend: {position: 'none'},
        }
    });
    hackChart.draw();

    var rCandlestickChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'CandlestickChart',
        containerId: 'rCandle_div',
        options: {
            title: 'Distribution of Performance (Interquartile Range)',
            height: 250,
            width: 500,
            chartArea:{left:"10%",top:"10%",width:"80%",height:"60%"},
            hAxis: {textStyle: {fontSize:10}},
            vAxis: {minValue: 0, maxValue: 100, title: 'Percentile', titleTextStyle: {fontSize:10}, textStyle: {fontSize:10}},
            legend: {position: 'in'},
            animation: {duration:1500, easing:'out'},
            colors: ['#a4c2f4','#3c78d8']
        },
        view: {columns:[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]}
    });

    var rColumnChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'ColumnChart',
        containerId: 'rColumn_div',
        options: {
            title: 'Percent Satisfactory',
            height: 250,
            width: 500,
            chartArea:{left:"10%",top:"10%",width:"80%",height:"60%"},
            hAxis: {textStyle: {fontSize:10}},
            vAxis: {minValue: 0, maxValue: 100, title: '% Satisfactory', titleTextStyle: {fontSize:10}, textStyle: {fontSize:10}},
            legend: {position: 'in'},
            animation: {duration:1500, easing:'out'},
            colors: ['#a4c2f4','#3c78d8']
        },
        view: {columns:[5, 14, 15]}
    });

    var rTableChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'Table',
        containerId: 'rTable_div',
        options: {
            width: '300px',
            height: '500px',
            allowHtml: true,
            cssClassNames: {tableCell: 'styleRows', headerRow: 'styleHeader'}
        },
        view: {columns: [16, 5, 19]}
    });

    var formatter = new google.visualization.BarFormat({width: 100, drawZeroLine: true, min: -20, max: 20});
    formatter.format(data, 19);

    // Create the dashboard.
    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
        bind(entityFilter, [rBubbleChart, rCandlestickChart, rColumnChart, rTableChart]).
        bind(schoolFilter, gradeFilter).bind(gradeFilter, teacherFilter).
        bind(teacherFilter, [rBubbleChart, rCandlestickChart, rColumnChart, rTableChart]).
        bind(numberSlider, [rBubbleChart, rCandlestickChart, rColumnChart, rTableChart]).
        draw(data);


 google.visualization.events.addListener(rTableChart, 'ready', function() {
        google.visualization.events.addListener(rTableChart.getChart(), 'sort', function(event) {

            data.sort([{column: event.column, desc: !event.ascending}]);
            boxchartObject = rCandlestickChart.getChart();
            boxchartObject.draw(data);

            columnChartObject = rColumnChart.getChart();
            columnChartObject.draw(data);
          });
    });
```

Comment: Typically, the spreadsheets do return data in the correct format.  There are some exceptions, but I would expect you to have problems with data type before you sorted the data.  You can confirm column types by calling the `DataTable#getColumnType` method (pass in the index of the column to check the type of, eg `data.getColumnType(0);` should return `'string'`).  I suspect that there is something going on with the way you are sorting the data.  Can you post example code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @asgallant, I just posted the code.

Comment: I think the issue might have to do with redrawing the chart vs. redrawing the entire dashboard.  However, I tried to redraw the dashboard, but did not have luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the way you redraw the charts.  By calling the `ChartWrapper#getChart#draw` method, you are bypassing all of the ChartWrapper's parameters - including the `view` parameter which specifies the columns to use.  This is why you get the data type error.  You need to redraw the Dashboard (to avoid a clash between the sorting and the filters).  Use this:

```
var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));
google.visualization.events.addListener(rTableChart, 'ready', function() {
    google.visualization.events.addListener(rTableChart.getChart(), 'sort', function(event) {
        // set the sorting options in the table so they are preserved on redraw
        rTableChart.setOption('sortColumn', event.column);
        rTableChart.setOption('sortAscending', event.ascending);
        // convert the Table view column to a DataTable column
        var col = rTableChart.getView().columns[event.column];
        // sort the DataTable
        data.sort([{column: col, desc: !event.ascending}]);
        // redraw the dashboard
        dashboard.draw(data);
    });
});

dashboard.bind(schoolFilter, gradeFilter)
.bind(gradeFilter, teacherFilter)
.bind([entityFilter, teacherFilter, numberSlider], [rBubbleChart, rCandlestickChart, rColumnChart, rTableChart])
.draw(data);
```

To ensure that the `sort` event handler is set up properly, you should set up the Table wrapper's `ready` event before calling the Dashboard's draw method.

Update working example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/t5rkJ/4/

Comment: @asgallant...thanks!  Also, do I need to add code to sort 'descending' too?  I ask because I used the following filters:  "Entity = Teacher" and "Grade = Gr. 3".  It sorts perfectly (in ascending order) when I click the "PR Delta" header.  However, when it click it a second time, it does not sort correctly (e.g., it includes other entities in the list).  Then when I hit it again, it resorts in ascending order correctly.  Do I have to add a piece of code to also sort descending (if the table is already sorted ascending)?

Comment: The system was tracking sort direction correctly, but due to the way filtering works, you were getting the filtered row indices for an unsorted DataTable applied to the sorted results, which gave the wrong data to the charts.  I will correct my answer with the appropriate way to handle this.

Comment: @asgallant...In addition to the school and teacher performance, I tried to add some "student" entities to my chart.  These students just have a 2013 and 2014 percentile. (They do not have an Interquartile Range or a % Scoring Satisfactory because they are just one person...so I put 0 in those cells.)  I can get these bubble points (size=2) to show up for a few students, but as soon as I add a list, then I get the following error: "Cannot read property 'left' of undefined"...do you know what is causing this?

Comment: [Here is the link to my spreadsheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AukymWvA6LlzdHpwblVtSmU3ZXJOMGhUVFZiV3NnSkE&usp=drive_web#gid=0)

Comment: Also, your will be able to see the error on your jsfiddle example.  There is not a "Student" option on Entity...and the error will be thrown when you select this.

Comment: I'm getting that error no matter what you select for "entity".  I'll look into it.

Comment: If an entity has no value for the ColumnChart or CandlestickChart, fill in `null`, not 0, for the values (I think that leaving the cells blank in the spreadsheet will do this).  I made an updated fiddle that nulls out the "student" cells in columns 6-15, and the charts draw properly, with no errors: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/t5rkJ/5/

Comment: Yes, works for me now too!  Not sure why I didn't think of trying that, but thank you.

Comment: The behavior you saw should not have occured, even with 0's filled in.  I suggest filing a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list) about it.

Comment: That is what I was thinking about after I commented last...0 should be a valid value!  (In this example, 0% satisfactory, or the 0th percentile for the lowest student.)  Thanks for filing the bug report.